# Does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathsf{E}Y_{k}^{2}}{k^{2}}<\infty$ hold from i.i.d and $L^{1}$ assumption?

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Suppose random variables $X_{1},\ X_{2},\cdots$ are i.i.d and in
>   $L^{1}$.
>
> I want to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathsf{E}Y_{k}^{2}}{k^{2}}<\infty$$ where $Y_k$ is a truncation of $X_k$ i.e. $Y_{k}=X_{k}1_{\{|X_{k}|\leq k\}}$.

Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Define $X = X_1$, and set $p_j = P(|X| \in [j,j+1))$.

Then $$\mathbb{E}[Y_k^2] \leq \sum\limits_{j = 0}^k p_j (j+1)^2.$$  Then we can calculate \begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y_k^2]}{k^2} &\leq \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \sum\limits_{j = 0}^k \frac{p_j (j+1)^2}{k^2} \\
&= \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty p_j (j+1)^2\sum\limits_{k = j}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \\
&\leq 2\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty p_j (j+1)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{j} \\
&\leq 8\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty p_j j \\
&\leq 8 \mathbb{E}[X] \\
&< \infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you sure $\sum_{k=j}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{1}{j}$ in general? (up to a constant factor, sure... but not like that)

Comment: $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k^2} < \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac1{k-1} - \dfrac1k \right) = \dfrac1n$

Comment: Ah, I was about to refine my argument when you did it this way.  This looks good except I think the sum should be from $j=0$ to $k$.

Comment: @kayak But that's not what's written. I am merely pointing out an innocuous small problem in the current answer, which can be fixed in at least two minor ways. (Besides that, nice answer!)

Comment: Another way, with $X=X_1$, is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E[\frac{Y_k^2}{k^2}] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E[\frac{X^2 1_{\{|X|\leq k\}}}{k^2}] = E[X^2 \sum_{k\geq |X|}\frac{1}{k^2}]$.  (And independence is not needed).  This trick of using identically distributed to convert to a single random variable $X$ is similar to the classic Etemadi proof of the law of large numbers.

Comment: Yes, you're all correct; I've fixed those two errors.  And @Michael's solution is even nicer!

Comment: How about from @Michael 's argument, $E[X^{2}\sum_{k\geq|X|}\frac{1}{k^{2}}]\leq E[X^{2}\frac{2}{|X|}]=2E|X|<\infty$? It does not need your $p_j$ argument.

Comment: @kayak, Yeah, I think that's the (significantly) cleaner route.